# Seidenberg's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have a problem with the proof of this

**Lemma.** Let $K$ be a field, $R=K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, and $I\subset R$ a zero-dimensional ideal. For every $i$ there exists $g_i\in I\cap K[X_i]$, $g_i\neq 0$, such that $\gcd(g_i,g'_i)=1$. Then $I$ is a radical ideal.

Write $g_1$ as a product of $t$ irreducible polynomials $h_i$. One proves that $I$ is the intersection of the $t$ ideals $I+\langle h_i \rangle$ and the proof is clear to me. Then if we prove that each $I+\langle h_i \rangle$ is radical we finish. The text, after noticing this fact, claims: so we can suppose $g$ irreducible. This is the problem: what's the fact that make this supposition true? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [Tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: You're being a bit too vague about the context. I suppose $I$ is an ideal in $K[x]$? Is $K$ a (maybe algebraically closed) field? It doesn't seem that $g$ is generic, is it? From what you do say, I'd think that the author is simply saying that either $g$ is irreducible and $I=I+\langle h_i\rangle$, or you consider each of those ideals separately and then take the intersection, which doesn't really make a difference for what follows.

Comment: When post such a question give us all the details necessary to answer you. In this case you could say it clear that this is Proposition 3.7.15 from Kreuzer and Robbiano, *Computational Commutative Algebra*, volume 1. Furthermore, write the enounce of the result whose proof you can't understand, to help people to figure out what are you talking about.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that you don't know if $h_i\in I$ in order to replace $g_1$ by $h_i$. However, if $g_1$ is not necessary in $I$, still can prove $$I+(g_1)=\bigcap_{I=1}^t I+(h_i).$$ So, if you can prove that $I+(h_i)$ is radical, for all $i$, then $I+(g_1)$ is radical, too. Now there is no problem to reduce yourself to the case where $g_1$ is irreducible.

In fact, here is a slightly more general version of Seidenberg's Lemma:

**Lemma.** Let $K$ be a field, $R=K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$, and $I\subset R$ a zero-dimensional ideal such that $I\cap K[X_i]=(f_i)$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. Let $g_i=f_i/\gcd(f_i,f'_i)$ be the square-free part of $f_i$. Then $$\sqrt I=I+(g_1,\dots,g_n).$$